# attribute not found in window.__INITIAL_STATE__ though it is present

Tags: python, reactjs, scrapy, pycharm

I am trying to scrape from this page:
https://www.michaelkors.com/ikat-print-tiered-shirtdress/_/R-US_MU98WXUC1Z

And to scrape the color, I am checking window.**INITIAL_STATE** to see which list has the color.
This is my code

```
for color1 in data["pdp"]["rawJson"]["SKUs"][0]["color"]["displayName"]:
            colors.append(color1+ ',')
```

However, it shows key error: 'color' though I have rechecked quite a few times and color is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the "variant_values" in there:
`color = data["pdp"]["rawJson"]["SKUs"][0]["variant_values"]["color"]["displayName"]`